# How to add the StringBuffer in a generic type List<Model>?

Tags: java, android, generics, collections

How to add the StringBuffer in a generic type `list<Model>`. i want to add the StringBuffer in `List<Model>` but android studio force me change the generic to `List<Stringbuffer>`.

```
public List<DataModel> getdata(){
    DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();
    List<DataModel> data=new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE+" ;",null);
     StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
        String country = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("country"));
        String city = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("city"));
        dataModel.setName(name);
        dataModel.setCity(city);
        dataModel.setCounty(country);
        stringBuffer.append(dataModel);


    }
    data.add(stringBuffer);

    Log.i("Hello",""+data);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `StringBuffer`? If anything, you should be using `StringBuilder`. However, here you should be using neither. Instead, create a new `DataModel` object inside the loop, and add it to the `data` list, also inside the loop. Also, remember to close the `Cursor` when done with it.

Comment: Also, `List<Stringbuffer>` is misspelled. But @Andreas is right, you shouldn't ever use `StringBuffer`, at least not for the last 12 or 13 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42539491/how-to-add-the-stringbuffer-in-a-generic-type-listmodel?noredirect=1#comment72215647_42539491), you don't want to use `StringBuffer` (or the better `StringBuilder`) in this code.

Instead, create a new `DataModel` object inside the loop, and add it to the `data` list, also inside the loop.

Also, remember to close the [`Cursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) when done with it, preferably using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

```java
public List<DataModel> getdata(){
    List<DataModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try (Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE+" ;", null)) {
        int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name");
        int cityIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("city");
        int countryIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("country");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();
            dataModel.setName(cursor.getString(nameIdx));
            dataModel.setCity(cursor.getString(cityIdx));
            dataModel.setCountry(cursor.getString(countryIdx));
            data.add(dataModel);
        }
    }
    Log.i("Hello", data.toString());
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to return a List in the method, you cannot add the StringBuffer.
A possible solution is to save it to a private member in the class.

Comment: Why would that method need a private field? That makes no sense.